# unable to import coolname and wtforms_components

Tags: python, import

I am using `python 3.9.2` and `pip 21.0.1`. I've created a virtual environment. In that I installed `flask 1.1.2` and `Werkzeug 1.0.0`.
I tried to install `coolname==1.1.0` and `wtforms_components==0.10.5`, it says successfully installed but it is not importing files.
from `coolname` I want `generate_slug` package
and from `wtforms_components`, I want `TimeField`

What I have done to install them:
`pip install WTForms-Components==0.10.5`
`pip install coolname`

Can you please tell me how can I get these packages?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using the global interpreter instead of your virtual environment.

You need to check that your IDE's interpreter is configured to that virtual environment you created. if you want to run it from the command line you first need to activate it with `env_name\Scripts\activate` and then run it.

Comment: Thank you soo much...that worked properly
I miss that to enable virtual environment in VScode